# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to fetch data from data base and display it in dropdwonlist

DAO

```
public List<String> getAllDeparment() {
    String sql = "select dept_name from DEPATMENT";
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, String.class );}
```

Service

```
public List<String> getAllDept(){
    return departmentDao.getAllDeparment();
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/drop")
public String drop(@ModelAttribute Depatment depatment ,Model model){
    List<String> allDept = deparmentServcies.getAllDept();
    model.addAttribute("deptlist",allDept);
    return "drop";
}
```

jsp

```
<form:form commandName="depatment " method="post">
    <form:select path="deptName">
        <form:options items="${deptlist}" />
    </form:select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem has been solved

```
<form:form commandName="depatment" method="post">
    <form:select path="deptName" items="${depatments}">
    </form:select>
```